# Magento observer (sales_order_grid_collection_load_before), filter collection by a product attribute

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

So I'm working with `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` observer event at the moment, where I can get the collection being used through `$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();`, I'm just wondering, if it is possible to filter this collection by a product from the order attribute.
What I mean with that is the order grid collection has sub products related to that order, I need to only show orders if at least one of the products match a specific criteria (in my case, I've given the products an admin_id attribute, which is set to the administrator who added the product).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a very similar thing by doing the following:

1. Override the sales order grid block. To do this you will need to set up your own extension (it looks like you might already be doing this, but just in case, there is some handy doco in the [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module))

   ```
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Company_Module>
               <version>0.1.0</version>
           </Company_Module>
       </modules>
       <global>
           <blocks>
               <company_module>
                   <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
               </company_module>
               <adminhtml>
                   <rewrite>
                       <sales_order_grid>Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                   </rewrite>
               </adminhtml>
           </blocks>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
2. I then copied the /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php into my extensions folder at /app/code/local/Company/Module/Block/Sales/Order
3. In the copied file I changed the class name to `class Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`
4. I then changed the _prepareCollection function. In this case I was interested in grabbing the customer_group_id and customer_email from the sales_flat_order table

   ```
   protected function _prepareCollection() {
       $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
       // left join onto the sales_flat_order table, retrieving the customer_group_id and customer_email columns -< this can be expanded
       $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id=sales_flat_order.entity_id', array('customer_group_id'=>'customer_group_id', 'customer_email'=>'customer_email'), null, 'left');

       // grab the current user and get their associated customer groups (additional coding required to associate the customer groups to an admin user
       $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
       $roleId = implode('', $user->getRoles());
       $customerGroupIds = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load($roleId)->getCustomerGroupIds();
       $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');

       // if the admin user has associated customer group ids then find the orders associated with those
       // this would be where you would do your filtering of the products
       if (count($customerGroupIds)) {
           $orders->addAttributeToFilter('customer_group_id', array('in' => $customerGroupIds));
       }
       $orderIds = $orders->getAllIds();
       $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds));

       $this->setCollection($collection);

       return parent::_prepareCollection();
   }
   ```

You may not need the join to the sales_flat_order table...you might be able to do it just by doing the filtering in the second part of the _prepareCollection function shown above. In my case, I was displaying the customer_group_id and the customer_email in the grid so that the user could manually filter, if required.

Comment: Isn't customer_group_id in the sales_flat_order table though? In my case, the products aren't in the sales_flat_order, which is the reason it's making it hard for me. If I have a order, there are multiple products associated, all have a different 'admin_id' attribute, and I need to show only the orders that have at least one product where the 'admin_id' is that of the logged in admin.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, if you have a look at the code above, I do a left join onto the sales_flat_order table to retrieve it `$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id=sales_flat_order.entity_id', array('customer_group_id'=>'customer_group_id', 'customer_email'=>'customer_email'), null, 'left');`. You could do the same thing

Comment: Great, I had to override the class like you said, but I couldn't filter the items like you said, ended up having to loop through them all and remove any if they shouldn't be there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CCBlackburn How to add category filter in obsever, i tried this -> $category_products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('680','894','895')))
        ->setWebsiteId(2);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can access directly the product from the `order_grid_collection` (I don't think so) but you can join this collection with `sales_flat_order_item` and then filter as you wish.
HTH

Comment: How would I be able to add a list of the ids to the sales_flat_order_item, and won't they be emptied when you clear the cache?